# Loop through items and after set interval remove class from all whilst adding class to next item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a simple carousel which fades in/out of various images. The visual changes happen in CSS when JS changes the class.

This worked perfectly with two slides. Now I've introduced a third it does not and I can now see why it worked with 2 and doesn't with 3 or more.

Essentially what I'd like to achieve is this:

Every 7 seconds the script removes all instances of `slide--active` and adds it to the next item in the loop.

I'm using Jquery throughout the site, so it makes sense to utilise it. The CSS below can be ignored, I'm only interested in the class change.

```js
$('.slides').each(function(i, item) {
    setInterval(
        function() {
          $('.slide').toggleClass('slide--active');
        },
    7000 + i)
});
```

```css
.slide { 
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
  background: blue;
}
.slide--active { 
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide slide--active"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The problem here is the use of the `each()` function. It toggles the class on each slide and not just the current / next one. Instead, you should probably just toggle the current and the next only. Just loop through each `.slide` and check if it has `.slide--active`. If so, you know you are on the current slide. Just toggle it and toggle on the next. Then break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
setInterval(
  function() {
    var item = $(".slide--active");
    var next = item.next(".slide").length == 0 ? $('.slide').first() : item.next(".slide")
    item.removeClass("slide--active");
    next.toggleClass('slide--active');
  },
  2000)
```

This will remove the active class from the current element, and set the active class on the next element (or first element if current element is last)

**Demo**

```js
setInterval(
  function() {
    var item = $(".slide--active");
    var next = item.next(".slide").length == 0 ? $('.slide').first() : item.next(".slide")
    item.removeClass("slide--active");
    next.toggleClass('slide--active');
  },
  2000)
```

```css
.slide {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: blue;
}

.slide--active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li class="slide slide--active"></li>
  <li class="slide"></li>
  <li class="slide"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let currentIndex = 0;

const slides = $('.slide');
const numberOfSlides = slides.length;

setInterval(() => {

  // Find next item index
  currentIndex = ((currentIndex + 1) % numberOfSlides);

  // Remove class from all slides
  slides.removeClass('slide--active');

  // Add class to a next item
  slides.eq(currentIndex).addClass('slide--active')

}, 7000)
```

Or you can track previous index and just remove class from previous slide.

Answer (score 0):

As I explained in the comments, you should only toggle the current and the next slide. Finally reset to the first slide when the last slide is done.

```js
// Get the number of slides
let totalSlides = $('.slides .slide').length;

setInterval(function(){
  let current = false;
  $('.slide').each(function(i, item) {
    if(!current){
      if(item.classList.contains('slide--active')){
      
        if(i === totalSlides - 1)
        {
          $('.slide:first-child').addClass('slide--active');
        }
        item.classList.toggle('slide--active');
        current = true;
      }
    } else {
      item.classList.toggle('slide--active');
      current = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
}, 7000);
```

```css
.slide { 
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
  background: blue;
}
.slide--active { 
  background: red; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide slide--active"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
    <li class="slide"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the comment explaining why `each` wasn't the right method.